# Hide footer when keyboard appear ionic

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am facing  an issue with the `footer-bar` in a particular page.when an input is focused  the keyboard appear and the footer stay above the keyboard.

**HTML**

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content>
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </ion-content>
    <div class="bar dash-footer-col dash-footer bar-footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col dash-footer-col mycharts-footer-col footertopredboarder" <img src="img/icons/1.png" ng-click="go('home')">
                <div>
                    <h5>HOME</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col dash-footer-col mycharts-footer-col footer-top-boarder " ng-click="go('profile')">
                <img src="img/icons/2.png">
                <div>
                    <h5>PROFILE</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col dash-footer-col mycharts-footer-col footer-top-boarder" style="padding-top:0px;" ng-click="go('contact')">
                <img class="weather-icon" src="img/icons/3.png">
                <div style="height:1em;">
                    <h5>CONTACT</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col dash-footer-col mycharts-footer-col footer-top-boarder" ng-click="go('logout')">
                <img src="img/icons/4.png">
                <div>
                    <h5>LOGOUT</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-view>
```

I have tried to resolve this issue by adding the below line in `app.js`. After the footer is hiding,But there is a flickering issue.Is there any other way to  hide the footer when the keyboard appear?
Please help me.Thanks.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the class `"hide-on-keyboard-open"` you can use for such things

```
<div class="hide-on-keyboard-open">
```

Take a look at [ionic keyboard plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/keyboard/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', function(){
        document.body.classList.add('keyboard-openC');
    });

 window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', function(){
        document.body.classList.remove('keyboard-openC');
    });
```

you can try this (on run() ). You'll just add the correct css rule and it should be ok.